# How to calculate the definite integral $\int_0^\pi \frac{\sin(x)^3}{(1-v \cdot \cos(x))^5} \, dx$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

The following definite integral once appeared in an electrodynamics exam:
 $$\int_0^\pi \frac{\sin(x)^3}{(1-v \cdot \cos(x))^5} \, dx = \ ?$$ How would you calculate that just using pen and paper (no calculators)?

Comment: What is $v$? Any real?

Comment: Yes, it can be an arbitrary real number.

Comment: Unless you list some value for $v$, calculator won't help you either

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set $v\cos x=u\,$, we have
$$I=\frac{1}{v^3}\int_{-v}^{v}\frac{v^2-u^2}{(1-u)^5}du=-\frac{1}{v^3}\int_{-v-1}^{v-1}\frac{v^2-(u+1)^2}{u^5}du$$

Comment: Unfortunately, I should get a result that doesn't contain a new integral...

Comment: Without changing variable ?

Comment: So sorry, I can't do it.

Comment: Well, you can change the variable, but the problem is that we now have to solve the $\int \frac{v^2-(u+1)^2}{u^5}du$, which isn't particularly easy either, I think.

Comment: **Hint:**   if  $v>1$ then $-v-1<0<v-1$ or if $v<-1$  then $v-1<0<-v-1$

Comment: @Quasar, but this integral is elementary. It's just simple algebra. Expand $(u+1)^2$ and then integrate each term of the sum separately

Comment: You wrote *Unfortunately, I should get a result that doesn't contain a new integral*. What has been given to you is the way to get the result. From this, everything becomes simple (just as You're In My Eye commented).

Comment: Now I see it. Sorry.

Comment: One last question: if you substitute $u=1-u$ in the second step, shouldn't it be $+ \frac{1}{v^3} \int_{-v-1}^{v-1}$ ... We get a minus from the Substitution and one from switching the limits $v-1$ and $-v-1$

Comment: @Quasar No, Note $u\to u+1$ so $v\to v-1$ and $-v\to -v-1$

Comment: Now it's clear to me. Thank you very much for your patience.

Comment: @Behrouz Maleki: I got confused again: If you substitute y=u+1 wouldn't then $v$ go to $v+1$ and $-v$ go to $-v+1 $ like in example 1 on Wikipedia's article about integration by substitution?

Comment: @Quasar, No please note, set $u=y+1$, we have $v=y+1$ and $-v=y+1$, therefore $y=v-1$ and $y=-v-1$, right?

Comment: @Behrouz Maleki: I think it's important to note the difference between substituting $x^2+1$ by u and setting  $u=y+1$ for example. Just as a test: For the integral in this question is it be equivalent to set u=y+1 and to substitute y=u-1? I think so. Could you please check it too, then I will close the question once again.

Comment: @Quasar Yes.Please note , generally we have $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=\int_{a-c}^{b-c}f(x+c)dx$ and  $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=\int_{a+c}^{b+c}f(x-c)dx$